Change default Dear ImGui widget width
The Dear ImGui default widget width (combo, inputtext, etc.) is too wide for my liking. I'd like to change the default width of these widgets once at application start-up, or maybe every time in the frame-loop. I can't find another solution however than modifying the widget width in every window again using ImGui::PushItemWidth() (does not work in frame-loop). Is a solution at application top-level or in the frame-loop possible?
